# AWS textract SDK Analyze expense error- unsupported document type

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

Hi I am trying to use the AWS-SDK for node js to analyse invoices. When I try to analyze single page invoices it works fine, but as soon as I send an invoice with more than one page through it immediately errors out the API call with an unsupported document error. Is there any way to solve this?